# can a style sheet obtain a class or id to dynamically change it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I use CORS to pull down pages and their CSS.  I store the CSS in a style tag and append it to the head.   Each time i load a page i want to wipe out the CSS.

Is there an easy way to do this?  I was thinking giving it an id or class, but i wasnt sure if that was allowed.  neither of them are optional attributes of  BUT under the definition of class, it can go on an element, and i figured that  was technically an element.

Does anyone know how this would be done?

the way i do it currently for populating it is:

```
var CSS = ".....";
var $style = $("<style type='text/css' />").append(CSS);
$("head").append($style);
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @putvande *"Is there an easy way to do this?"* referring to *"Each time i load a page i want to wipe out the CSS"*

Comment: yes and i was thinking that each time i load the CORS object, wipe out the content in a desired Style Tag, as there are multiple... so the Root question is as simple as:  Can i add an id or class such that i can use JQuery to select it, AND make sure it is still valid HTML etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`style` elements are elements like any other, and if you remove the element, the CSS styles it defines are removed.

So if you have a specific style element you've added, as with your code in your question, you can remove it just by doing this:

```
$style.remove();
```

...since you already have a reference to it in the `$style` variable.

Alternately, give the specific `style` element you want to remove an `id` or class, and then use that to remove it:

```
// Adding ...
var CSS = ".....";
var $style = $("<style type='text/css' />").append(CSS).addClass("dynamic");
$("head").append($style);

// Removing later...
$("style.dynamic").remove();
```

You can also just update the text of your existing element, which will update the styles it defines.

Answer (score 1):

You can delete all the stylesheets like this:

```
$('link[type="text/css"], style').remove();
```

Comment: The OP said they're adding style dynamically.  Which as you say would suffice for just `$('style');` but the OP also said they want to remove ALL styles and hence if there were any attached stylesheets the answer above would cover those too as potentially via CORS you aren't sure what other styles the pages will contain.

Comment: i see you updated... i was talking about style[type=text/css], the link one makes sense. well, it really should be [rel=stylesheet] since text/css is assumed these days, but again, i was talking about typing the style tag...

Comment: actually my question is "can i add an id or class to a style tag.  I wasnt sure if it was valid.... as i wanted to know how to delete some blocks of css in a dynamic fashion.

Answer (score 0):

You can find and remove all the `style` tags with `$("style[type='text/css']").remove()`, or you can store `$style` as a global var and then call `$style.remove()`